# GCP Function Missing Attribute, Converting PDFs to MP3s

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, accessibility, ocr

I'm trying to replicate this GCP project, where a couple of developers created a GCP function that could perform Optical Character Recognition on PDFs, extract the text, and then convert the text to an MP3. [Link to the video for that project can be seen here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-nvbuc59Po)

I work in accessibility, so this will be an incredible solution for my users, but I am running into a couple issues.

I created the storage bucket for the PDFs, then went to create the function, [and used the code from one of the developer's github, linked here.](https://github.com/kazunori279/pdf2audiobook/blob/master/functions/app/main.py)

However, I running into this error when trying to deploy the function:

[image: GCP Function Error, missing attribute]

```
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: File main.py is expected to contain a function named hello_gcs
Detailed stack trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v1.py", line 315, in check_or_load_user_function
_function_handler.load_user_function()
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v1.py", line 193, in load_user_function
self._user_function = getattr(main_module, _ENTRY_POINT)
AttributeError: module 'main' has no attribute 'hello_gcs'
```

This is probably a really easy fix, but I have't played around with GCP functions all that much. Any suggestions for fixing this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out! There was an original snippet of code when I first created the function, that I deleted when pasting the developer's code. I pasted the original snippet back in, and now it's deploying just fine! Now to see if I can figure out the rest of the project lol.

Comment: nice you could figured out the solution. Could you please accept your own answer so the community can identify the solution to this question?

Comment: It says I can accept my own answer by tomorrow. I will do that then!